# How can I begin MySQL work in Node.js on Windows?

Tags: mysql, database, node.js

I've begun playing around with Node.js lately, for many reasons but most importantly the ease at which I can write a chat-server utilising HTML5 WebSockets. However, I've been stuck for weeks with MySQL.

I'm currently using this MySQL client module: https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native

I've connected to the database and managed to store data using the following code:

```
// MySQL database
var db = require("mysql-native").createTCPClient(); // localhost:3306 by default
db.auto_prepare = true;
db.auth(dbName, dbUser, dbPass);
// Update the database
db.execute("UPDATE server_data SET value='" + new Date() + "' WHERE name='lastLoaded'");
```

How may I go about retrieving data from the database using a `SELECT * FROM x WHERE y=z` query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you chose `nodejs-mysql-native` over [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) which is a really good node module. If there is none, then you should probably try `node-mysql`. I've tried it and it is great to start off using MySQL with Node. You could do something like:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'your_username',
  password : 'your_password',
});

connection.connect();

connection.query("UPDATE server_data SET value=? WHERE name=?", [new Date(), 'lastLoaded'] function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Result: ', result);
});

connection.end();
```

The advantage you get by using it this way is that you can prevent SQL injection, which is taken care of internally in node-mysql (by using the connection.escape() method).

Comment: Thanks for that advice! I've successfully installed that module! The reason I chose nodejs-mysql-native is because it seemed like the logical choice for my windows machine. Thanks again.

Comment: Just go through the documentation on the `node-mysql` page. The guy who wrote this module, Felix, is very well regarded in the node community. The development of this module is very active too.